# How to prevent SIGINT in child process from propagating to and killing parent process?

Tags: c, linux, process, sqlite, fork

I've recently learned how to do the whole `fork/exec/wait` thing and ended up writing some code that looked like this stripped down:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t x = fork();
  if (x == 0) {
    execlp("sqlite3", "sqlite3");
    printf("exec failed\n");
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Hi\n");
  }
}
```

This works out pretty well, and actually ends up opening the `sqlite3` shell, but there's one problem. If you `Ctrl + C` out of the `sqlite3` shell, then it also terminates the parent process and the line `printf("Hi\n")` never runs.

I assumed this was because the SIGINT was being propagating to the parent process, and after looking into it further, I read that a SIGINT will terminate all processes in the same group, meaning since the parent and child share the same group they're both terminated.

I tried to fix this by doing trying to call `setpgid` like so:

```
int main() {
  pid_t x = fork();
  if (x == 0) {
    setpgid(getpid(), getpid()); // <-- Added in this line
    execlp("sqlite3", "sqlite3");
    printf("exec failed\n");
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Hi\n");
  }
}
```

which ran fine, but that broke the `sqlite3` prompt. Moreover `Ctrl + C` still killed the parent in this case. I decided to try to narrow it down even more, and then found something weird, and got stumped. Just putting a `getpid()` call into the fork will make `execlp()` fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t x = fork();
  if (x == 0) {
    getpid(); // <--- just adding this in makes it fail
    execlp("sqlite3", "sqlite3");
    printf("exec failed\n");
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Hi\n");
  }
}
```

and not even just for `sqlite3`, but for simple stuff like `execlp("ls", "ls")` as well (this might be unrelated to the original question though).

I'm in a bit over my head and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I'm not quite sure what to do from here.

- I'm on OSX 10.11, and am compiling with clang.
- `clang --version`: Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: _"If you Ctrl + C out of the sqlite3 shell, then it also terminates the parent process"_ Because Ctrl+C would cause Bash to send SIGINT to the process it spawned (i.e. your C program), not to whichever process happens to be reading from stdin at the time.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo hmm I see! So I need to send `Ctrl + C` to the foreground? Also why isn't this the case when I do `execlp("bash", "bash")`?  That handles `Ctrl + C` just fine.

Comment: You already are. As far as bash is concerned, your process is the foreground process, while `sqlite3` is just some other process who happens to be using the same stdin pipe. You could handle ctrl+c in your C program and send sqlite3 SIGTERM, or use Ctrl+D to send EOF to stdin, which sqlite3 will pick up and interpret as the end of the stdin stream.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo hey I added a quick edit to the original comment, but to restate "Also why isn't this the case when I do `execlp("bash", "bash")`? That handles `Ctrl + C` just fine."

Comment: Fix the worst bug first: it should be `execlp("bash", "bash", NULL);` -- the `NULL` is **required** to terminate the argument list for `execl()`, `execlp()`, and `execle()`. Then, if you want to handle Ctrl+C in the parent process, just install a signal handler that will forward the `SIGINT` signal to the child process.

Comment: I imagine bash does some special setup with the terminal to capture and interpret ctrl+c so that it can send SIGINT to its children. The child bash process' overwrites the setup of the parent one.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'd hate to not give you credit for all your comments. You mind just copy and pasting them all into the answer box as a whole so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: Aren't keyboard signals sent to the entire foreground process group, not just a single process?

Comment: @Barmar after the comment chain above, and my own experimentation I think so. I would mark this question as resolved in some way, but no one answered.

Comment: You could just delete it if it's no longer in need of answering.

Comment: @Barmar well I've linked to it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477988/calling-kill-on-a-child-process-with-sigterm-terminates-parent-process-but-call, and additionally I prefer to make a community wiki with the contents of the comments, but I was waiting to see if they would post the answer themselves before I do it for them.

Answer (score -1):

you can either catch the SIGINT or write a signal handler.
use the code below:

```
signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGINT)
    printf("received SIGINT\n");
}
```